# How to have multiple get params in an URL?

Tags: python, django, url, get, request

I'm using Django to create a website, and in one portion I need two get requests in the url - one called "search", and one called "page". I've tried the following -

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/explore/?search=test/?page=1')
```

However, '/?page=1' is being included as part of the search, and this is messing it up. Any way to keep them as two different gets, or will I have to fuse them into one?

Comment: '/explore/?search=test&page=1' ?? if you ment "get params"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/explore/?search=test&page=1')
```

and in view you can get both parameters as:

```
search = request.GET.get('search')
page = request.GET.get('page')
```